# How to work with Xcode server in Xcode 9? Do we need to have Xcode 9 open always?

Tags: continuous-integration, ios11, xcode-server, xcode9

I was using Xcode server app for setting up CI-CD in my project till now. I came to know that from Xcode 9, there is no need of server.app and we can setup xcode server in **Xcode 9 IDE** itself.

I couldn't test this now since i have my previous projects setup with Xcode server running in my mac and if i setup Xcode server in Xcode 9, those will not work. 
I just want to understand on how Xcode server works with Xcode 9.

Can i do both my development as well as CI-CD setup both in the same IDE?

If so do i need to have my Xcode open always to keep the server running and what will there be any performance impact on my Xcode if i have it running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Xcode Server built into Xcode 9 functions very similar to the current setup using Xcode 8 and the Server.app. The main difference is the Server.app is no longer required, and all of the web/api components are bundled with Xcode.app.

Just like the Xcode 8/Server 5.3.x setup, a dedicated user account will be setup on the machine you wish to use as your Xcode CI Server. All integrations will be processed using this account. Therefore you do not need to have your accounts copy of Xcode.app running all the time, and one machine can function as both your standard IDE and CI server.

Comment: So all the Xcode server setup steps remains the same? How to creating and linking repositories work here?

Comment: @yaali If you're asking about the Hosted Repositories feature... this has been removed from Xcode Server (Xcode 9).